# Jmeter configuration In Local Webapplication

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, load, jmeter, load-testing

I am new to Jmeter, i want to do the load testing to my web application which is developed using JSF 1.2, i read many articles about it,And i surfed in google every where i got very simple example, that how we can do the load testing to a simple static website like apache.jemter.org, but i couldn't find the procedure to  do load testing a local web application.

I have some questions:

- In my application first login page.After passing username,password and branch i will click Login button, it will navigate to home page. 
  Here my question is

  I want to test my home page /jsf/pages/login/home.xhtml, Now whether i need to pass username,password and branch as parameters or not required. If yes how jmeter will look in to my code and gather that info, since it is a POST request.
- There are some cookies also involved, how can I handle this?
- If I want test some 10 pages/processes in my application, whether I need to configure all the 10 pages in JMeter, including the parameters required to execute that process?

Kindly do help me.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to start with writing a regular expression to extract jsfViewState

**Regular Expression Extractor**

`<input type="hidden" name="javax\.faces\.ViewState" id="javax\.faces\.ViewState" value="([^"]+)".*/>`

save it with a reference name of lets say `jsfViewState`

**POST - authenticate**

use something like that, adopt IDs to your own page

[image]

**Cookies**

Thats pretty straight forward, just add HTTP Cookie Manager at the end of your test and set it to Compatibility/HC3CookieHandler. You should also add a HTTP Header Manager at the end, no settings required.

**Conclusions**

after doing all that start with your proper testing using assertions, loops etc. Just keep in mind that you have to pass `jsfViewState` with your POST requests. There's a nice extension for Chrome called [BlazeMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/231479-chrome-extension) that will help you extract post information from your pages.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could realize login authentication using [this detailed video tutorial](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/80479-how-to-use-jmeter-for-login-authentication).
2. To handle cookies, use [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager). Just add it to
3. You could configure manually all this requests or you use HTTP Proxy [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder) to record your cases.